# Copying files to newly created folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working on a script that iterates through a spreadsheet and creates folders (within a parent folder) based on the values in the selected range. Then the script is supposed to copy files from a separate folder into each of the newly created folders.

Everything works well except that the files are being copied into the source folder instead of the newly created ones. I can't understand why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxxxx').getSheetByName('xxxxx');
var countries = ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 1);
var values = countries.getValues();

var sourceFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx'); //Folder containing files to be copied
var files = sourceFiles.getFiles();
var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx'); //Parent folder for each new folder

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var newFolder = targetFolder.createFolder(values[i]).getId();

    while(files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.makeCopy(newFolder).setName(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- Data retrieved by `getValues()` is the 2 dimensional array.

  - In your case, from `ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 1)`, it seems that `values` is `[[value1], [value2],,, ]`.
- When you want to give the filename for `makeCopy()`, you can use `makeCopy(name, destination)`.

  - In this case, `destination` is `Folder`.
- In your script, at `file.makeCopy(newFolder).setName(file.getName())`, `file` is copied to the same folder of `file`, because `newFolder` is a string. But the filename of `file` is given by `setName(file.getName())`.

  - I think that this is the reason for the error.

The modified script which reflected above points is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxxxx').getSheetByName('xxxxx');
var countries = ss.getRange(2, 1, 50, 1);
var values = countries.getValues();

var sourceFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx'); //Folder containing files to be copied
var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx'); //Parent folder for each new folder

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var files = sourceFiles.getFiles(); // Modified
    var newFolder = targetFolder.createFolder(values[i][0]); // Modified

    while(files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.makeCopy(file.getName(), newFolder); // Modified
    }
}
```

### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the answer a little prematurely. Your solution is very helpful, however the while loop appears to only be running during the first iteration. I've come to this conclusion because only the first folder is populated with the files. Its so close. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @rylaughlin I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. I moved ``sourceFiles.getFiles();``.``FileIterator`` retrieved by ``getFiles()`` has to be retrieved again, after ``while (files.hasNext()) {}``. I have forgot this. I'm sorry. Please confirm it.

Comment: Please, no need apologize. I should have figured it out. It works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @rylaughlin Thank you for your concern. I'm glad your problem was solved.